# Magento 2.3 sage pay credit card not working

Tags: magento2.3

We are using porto theme and configure sage pay payment getaway for credit card but its not working. Displaying error:

```
Error 1002 - Authentication failed
```

Please help me...!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. please post your error here.

Comment: We are getting this error while using the creditt card sage pay option.                      
Error 1002 - Authentication failed