# Sage Pay Issue Magento 2.3 (Porto Theme)

Tags: magento2.3, porto-theme

I am using the porto theme with magento 2.3 version but i can't able to place order using sage pay credit card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.3 sage pay credit card not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327631/magento-2-3-sage-pay-credit-card-not-working)

Comment: Please dont add same question with different content. Its best you edit that question and provide available details you have. Good luck